# slide.toggle menu is working fine in all browser but not in default android browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

The slide.toggle menu is working fine in all browsers but not in default android browser
I use this script for slide, hide show the toggle menu:

```
$('#menubutton').click(function() {
    $('.menuslider').slideToggle(600);
}
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 600) {
        $('.menuslider').show();
    }
    if($(window).width() < 600) {
        $('.menuslider').hide();
    }
}
```

When i lose the 'facebook like button script' the slider is working, but slide at the diagonal. So i'm a little confused..

Here you can see the slidermenu in action 
http://www.vinoecucina.nl/test/test.html

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These can help.

Clean up all the errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#menubutton').click(function() {
    $('.menuslider').slideToggle(600);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 600) {
        $('.menuslider').show();
    }
    if($(window).width() < 600) {
        $('.menuslider').hide();
    }
});
```